# site-wide search and replace vim cdo no buffers

Tags: vim, ag

I recently switched to vim, and learnt that you can execute searching using AG.

I always do

```
:Ag foo
```

And, in the quicklist window

```
:cdo s/foo/bar/g |update
```

However,it opens all the files in buffers.How can I not let Vim open buffers,but let vim replace words?

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't worry about those buffers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use :cfdo and close all the buffers you've opened and modified:

```
:cfdo :bd
```

So the workflow is as follows:

```
:Ag foo
:cdo %s/bar/baz/g | update 
:cfdo :bd
```

While :cdo iterates over each entry in the quickfix list, :cfdo moves over each file referenced in the list.